# How to count elements on multidimensional array in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some document like this

```
db.instructors.insertMany( [
{
"name": "A",
"dept_name": "CS",
"salary": 68000,
"teaches": [ { course_id: "CS-101", year: 2018 }, { course_id: "CS-347", year: 2018 } ]
},
{
"name": "C",
"dept_name": "Finance",
"salary": 90000,
"teaches": [ { course_id: "FIN-201", year: 2016 }, { course_id: "FIN-301", year: 2017 }, { course_id: "FIN-320",
year: 2017 } ]
},
{
"name": "B",
"dept_name": "Biology",
"salary": 72000,
"teaches": [ { course_id: "BIO-101", year: 2016 }, { course_id: "BIO-201", year: 2017 }, { course_id: "BIO-101",
year: 2018 } ]
}
] );
```

I have to find the name, department name, and the salary of each instructor who has salary higher than 75,000 and has taught 2 courses. If an instructor has taught the same course N times, it is counted as N courses.
I figured out that I have to use aggregate, but I cannot display the department name and salary of each instructor.
Here my code:

```
db.instructors.aggregate([{
   $match: {
     salary: {$gt: 75000}
   }},
   { $unwind: "$teaches" },
   {
     $group:
       {
         _id: "$name",
         totalCourses:
           {
             $sum: 1
           }
       }
   },
   {
     $match: {
       totalCourses: 2
     }
   }

 ]);
```

Comment: Is the criteria "has taught exactly 2 courses" or "has taught at least 2 courses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify this :

```
 _id: "$name"
```

to

```
 _id: {"$name" , "$dept_name" , "$salary"}
```

or you can do the better:

```
 db.instructors.aggregate([ {$match:{salary:{$gt:75000}}  }  , {   $project: { name:1,"dept_name":1  ,"salary":1 ,  numberOfCourses: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$teaches" }, then: { $size: "$teaches" }, else: "NA"} }       }    } ,{$match:{"numberOfCourses":2}}    ])
```

to avoid the "expensive"  unwind operation ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single query using the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator:

```
db.instructors.find({ salary: { $gt: 75000 }, teaches: { $size: 2 }})
```